# Can I change the list style used when Word (2007) auto-creates a bulleted list?

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word, word-2007

I have a template where I've created a custom list style, and ensured that that list style is used when the user clicks on the "bullet" icon on the ribbon (by overriding `FormatBulletDefault`).

However, if the user types:

> `* foo`

...then Word will automatically turn that into a bulleted list using the "wrong" (default) list style, which is not the one I want to use. This will mean that users end up with wrongly-formatted lists.

If I could turn off the "automatically create bulleted lists" setting *for my template*, then I might consider that, but it's an application setting, and I don't want to turn it off for all documents.

Is there any way to intercept the auto-creation of a bulleted list? Or to change the list style it uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any way to intercept this behavior as it is being caused by Word's AutoCorrect AutoFormat As You Type functionality. However you can turn off the Apply as you type|Automatic bulleted lists behavior temporarily. To do so, add the following code to Private Sub Document_Open():

```
ActiveDocument.Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeApplyBulletedLists = False
```

This will turn off this functionality for Word globally (and as such will affect concurrently opened documents), but if you include the reverse in Private Sub Document_Close():

```
ActiveDocument.Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeApplyBulletedLists = True
```

the setting will be restored. You can find the Word object model mappings for the AutoFormat As You Type functionality here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee692775.big_asyoutype(en-us,TechNet.10).jpg

and an article explaining the VBA implementation of these settings here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692775.aspx

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, although I wouldn't want to blindly set the autoformat option to True given that the user might have already disabled it. I guess I could store the "before" value. Also, taking this one step further, I suppose I could trap the "window activate" event, so that I can turn the setting on and off as the user activates/de-activates documents based on my template. That way other documents would be unaffected.

Comment: Gary, I completely agree: if one chooses the solution I suggested trapping the "before" value and activating/deactivating the documents is the way to go. Thanks for the great dialog.